# PLSQL - variable at the end of the Loop Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was reviewing a colleague's code and found something similar below:

```
begin
    for i in (select 'x' from dual) loop
        null;
    end loop Y; 
end;
```

I can't understand why this compiles and runs.
Shouldn't it fail because of the "Y" variable?
I tried other variables as well but it compiles.

please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

These are just statement labels and exist to name a particular part of the program, it's not much different from the label you put after the begin end of a procedure to mark the end of the procedure.

[For reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/FOR-LOOP-statement.html)

Comment: Your reference link is for MySQL, here's one for Oracle db: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/FOR-LOOP-statement.html

Comment: Silly me, thank you for the remark, adjusted it.